# Desktop app resolution Windows 11

Tags: resolution, windows-11

I hope this is the right community for asking this question.

I recently installed an app that is quite old on my new Windows 11 machine with k4 screen resolution.

What happens is that the app text and graphics in general are extremely small. I suppose this is related to the high resolution of the PC with respect to the low resolution of the app.

Is there a way to make this app usable on this machine?

Comment: Try changing scale (Settings Display) and see if the app responds. If not, nothing you can do.

Comment: Thank seems to work, is it possible to scale only for a certain app and not for everything?

Comment: i think i found the solution https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-change-scaling-for-specific-apps-in-windows-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-change-scaling-for-specific-apps-in-windows-11), just go on the shortcut of the app, right click and go to preferences, compatibility and customize behaviour for high DPI display